# Trigger next and previous element in 'vue-owl-carousel' package Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have problem with triggering next or previous item in `vue-owl-carousel` package in Vue with javascript.

Can anybody help?

Carousel code :

```
<carousel id="newGamesCarousel" :items="1" :dots="false" :nav="false" :margin="10" :key="refresh">
  <div class="newGames-item" v-for="item in newProducts">
    <div class="details">
      <div class="labels flex-wrap">
        <span class="mb-1" v-for="platform in item.platforms">{{platform.name}}</span>
        <span class="mb-1" v-for="region in item.regions">ریجن {{region.name}}</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="gameTitle">{{item.name}}</h2>
      <div class="priceBox">
        <router-link class="add-to-cart" :to="{path: '/game/'+item.id+'/'+stringToSlug(item.title)+''}">+</router-link>
        <div class="price">
          <div class="former" v-if="item.sale_percent !== false">
            <span class="percent">%{{item.sale_percent}}</span>
            <span class="total">{{item.price}}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="later">
            {{item.regular_price}}
            <span class="unit">تومان</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <figure class="image">
      <img v-bind:src="item.thumbnail_url" v-bind:alt="item.name">
    </figure>
  </div>
</carousel>
```

And the next and previous buttons:

```
<div class="arrows">
  <svg class="nextCarousel" id="newGamesNext" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <use xlink:href="/src/assets/imgs/sprite.svg#arrow"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg class="prevCarousel" id="newGamesPrev" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <use xlink:href="/src/assets/imgs/sprite.svg#arrow"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: share some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per documentation described here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel

> Custom prev and next buttons using slot, the buttons will be hidden
>   while start and end in non-loop mode
>
> ```
> <carousel>
>
>   <template slot="prev"><span class="prev">prev</span></template>
>
>   <template slot="next"><span class="next">next</span></template>
>
> </carousel>
> ```

within the `carousel` tag after adding all your slides

you can add `<template slot="{{prev/next}}">{{add your icon image here }}</template>` and it should take care of the previous and next events on its own

```
<template slot="prev">
   <svg class="nextCarousel" id="newGamesNext" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><use xlink:href="/src/assets/imgs/sprite.svg#arrow"></use></svg>
</template>
```

this is what I feel should solve your issue. If Im missing something feel free to add urls of documentations/ tutorials that you followed to get your code here. please let me know if the solution worked  or not

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-flex>
  <span @click="$refs.prev.click()">
      PREVIOUS
  </span>
  <span @click="$refs.next.click()">
      NEXT 
  </span>
</v-flex>


<v-flex>

  <carousel>

   <template slot="prev"><span hidden ref="prev" class="prev">prev</span></template>

   <template slot="next"><span hidden  ref="next" class="next">next</span></template>

  </carousel>

</v-flex>
```

Comment: Do not post only code solution. Please add some details to your answer.